# Azure: Getting data for Todo list

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I followed the [tutorial for Azure authentication from Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/).
It works. I can authenticate myself. 
When I click on the Todo list tab, I'm getting the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> 
<html><head> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> 
<h1>Not Found</h1> 
<p>The requested URL /api/TodoList was not found on this server.</p></body></html>
```

Is the server my server or the one from Azure? Do I have to add something in my Azure Portal like a database?

A tutorial how to get data would be nice!

Comment: according your error message, it seems the request is directly against to your server, but handled by angular route. You need to check your angular route provider's configuration. Like mentioned at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/#em3-use-adal-to-secure-pages-in-the-spaem. It's more related to a pure angular issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is there is no "api" folder or route. 
`return $http.get('/api/TodoList');` is called to get an item. So how should I get the item from my server? I have no items.

Comment: It depends on you how to implement your backend server. You have not implemented this endpoint. And it's too board here.